# Documentation for the MIT PDP-1X OS

Tags: history, pdp-1, reference-request

The PDP-1x is a Digital Equipment Corporation PDP-1 computer modified to support both ones and twos complement arithmetic, and to include a memory management unit.  It ran a locally developed operating system with specific facilities to represent virtualized devices and inter-process communications.  The top-level element was called a "Sphere".  It contained resources (called capabilities) and execution elements.  I believe the execution elements were called "processes".

There was a manual for the OS named "INSTR5 ALL".  I would like to read more about the OS to see if I was just a youngster amazed by something I was unfamiliar with, or if this operating system was unique and worthy of re-examination today.

Where could I find documentation of the PDP-1x Operating System?

Comment: Is [this doc](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/mit/rle_pdp1/ESL-R-140_PDP1_TS_Jun62.pdf) related in any way?  Probably not, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to post it just in case.

Comment: This looks to predate the changes which turned the pdp1 into the pdp1x.  Good for  history, and I will read it.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm still hoping to find the documentation for the PDP-1x OS.

Comment: I'm very interested in this, because the MIT Logo group SITS operating system for their PDP-11/45 also has capabilities and the concept of a "sphere".  As far as I can see, they mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: The basic ideas for spheres, capabilities, etc were laid out in
http://publications.csail.mit.edu/lcs/pubs/pdf/MIT-LCS-TR-023.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe this is the best place for PDP-1X documentation:

http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/mit/rle_pdp1/
(Linking to a mirror because the main bitsavers.org is offline for the moment.)

[The 1975 memo PDP35, part 5A](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/mit/rle_pdp1/memos/pdp35_part5A_feb75.pdf) documents spheres and capabilities:

> A virtual memory space, any virtual processors (processes) that might be executing inside that memory space, plus the list of associated resources (C-list) comprise a *sphere*.

Interestingly, these exact concepts - spheres, processes, capabilities - were carried forward to the MIT Logo group timesharing system SITS.

Comment: Lars, this is exactly what I couldn't find.  Thank you.  -- Carl